# How to use Core Midi framework in iPhone application?

Tags: ios4

Can someone tell me what is the basic purpose of MIDI framework and how can it be used to create a musical application?

Answer (score 2):

Core Midi is just for Midi I/O - message in and out. What you do with them is another part of the puzzle. For Midi I/O - a good tutorial is PGMidi http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/pgmidi-updated.html. If you want to make some sounds you could try adapting mobileSynth http://code.google.com/p/mobilesynth/